# Take random samples based on two groups in r

Tags: r, random

I have data with two columns; ID and specialty. Each ID has two occurrences with unique occurrences of specialty. I would like to take random sample of data with 400 from each specialty group with 2 occurrences of ID. I have tried dplyr group with sample_n, but it turns ID with different occurrences.

data example

```
specialty <- c("obs", "obs", "ped", "ped", "im", "im", "obs", "obs")
ID <- c("M", "M", "K", "K", "l", "l", "N", "N")
shift <- c("night", "day", "night", "day", "night", "day", "night", "day")
```

My desired output if I would sample 2 per specialty is

```
specialty <- c("obs", "obs", "im", "im", "ped", "ped")
ID <- c("M", "M", "l", "l", "K", "K")
shift <- c("night", "day", "night", "day", "night","day")
```

What I get is

```
specialty <- c("obs", "obs", "im", "im", "ped", "ped")
ID <- c("M", "M", "l", "k", "k", "N")
shift <- c("night", "day", "night", "night", "day", "day")
```

Comment: Instead of editing the question can you include the answer below in the answer section with the code that you used? It may help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Update
I have figured out a solution. I have concatenated each 2 consecutives rows with similar ID, then sampled by specialty. Finally, I have subset columns that represents consecutive rows and bind them as rows.

```
specialty <- c("obs", "obs", "ped", "ped", "im", "im", "obs", "obs")
ID <- c("M", "M", "K", "K", "l", "l", "N", "N")
shift <- c("night", "day", "night", "day", "night", "day", "night", "day")
d <- data.frame(specialty, ID, shift)

library(dplyr)
library(sqldf)
d2 <- subset(d, d$shift == "night")
d3 <- subset(d, d$shift == "day")
d4 <- sqldf("select * from d2 left join d3 on d2.ID = d3.ID", row.names = TRUE)
d5 <- d4 %>% 
      group_by(specialty)  %>%
      sample_n(size = 1)
d6 <- d5[, 1:3]
d7 <- d5[, 4:6]
colnames(d7) <- sub(".1", "", colnames(d7))
d8 <- rbind(d6, d7)
d8
```